# Asp.Net MVC4 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently working in asp.net mvc4. And implementing user profile information. My controller I-e **HomeController** contain;

```
public ActionResult Resume()
{
    using (ProfileInfo profile = new ProfileInfo())
    {
        return View(profile.ProfileGetInfoForCurrentUser());
    }
}
```

My **profileinfo** class contains a method wich return type 'ResumeViewModel';

```
public ResumeViewModel ProfileGetInfoForCurrentUser()
{
    ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName);
    ResumeViewModel resume = new ResumeViewModel();
    resume.Email = Membership.GetUser().Email.ToString();
    resume.FullName = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
    return resume;

}
```

Now my **ResumeViewModel** looks like this;

```
public class ResumeViewModel
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

While my view is strongly type of `'@model PortfolioMVC4.Models.ResumeViewModel'`. However, when I run this I get the following error;

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
{
Line 14:             ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(Membership.GetUser().UserName);
Line 15:             ResumeViewModel resume = new ResumeViewModel();
Line 16:             resume.Email = Membership.GetUser().Email.ToString();
Line 17:             resume.FullName = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
```

**I am getting error on line 15;** which is basically code that exist in ProfileGetInfoForCurrentUser method (as shown above).
I don't know what to do?
Any help regard to this is apreciatable;

Comment: why are you disposing your view model??

Comment: There is no way that line 15 will throw a NullReferenceException. Line 14 is more likely, perhaps Membership.GetUser() doesn't return a User, so accessing the UserName property fails.

Comment: it does return because on line 14, I am already a login user

Comment: Line numbers can be off by a few; if you *step through* the code in the IDE, which line is it that actually throws?

Comment: I removed using statement but It still didn't work

Comment: Also, is there any chance your `Email` is `null` ? then the `.ToString()` would throw

Comment: Why are you calling `Membership.GetUser()` sooo many times? Have you considered caching it in a local variable?

Comment: yes, the error is on line 16, when I step through code using debugger

Comment: So the Email is null and the ToString() call throws.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the Email property is null, so you cannot call the `.ToString` method on it. And by the way the [`MembershipUser.Email`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.email.aspx) property is already a string, so calling a `.ToString()` on it very hardly makes any sense.

Also I would recommend you calling the `Membership.GetUser()` method only once and caching the result into a local variable to avoid hammering your database with multiple requests:

```
public ResumeViewModel ProfileGetInfoForCurrentUser()
{
    var user = Membership.GetUser();
    ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(user.UserName);
    ResumeViewModel resume = new ResumeViewModel();
    resume.Email = user.Email;
    resume.FullName = user.UserName;
    return resume;
}
```

And by the way you seem to be declaring some `profile` variable without doing lots of useful things with it. Are you sure it's really necessary?

Comment: But this doesn't mean that there's an `Email` defined in the database. And so even if you are logged in the `Email` property could be null. So don't call `.ToString()` on a null object.

Comment: yes u r right, but I have also called profile.GetProfileGroup("AboutMe").GetPropertyValue("Website").ToString() which is a profile property.But when I remove toString(), I am getting cnno't convert from object to string

Comment: @DotNetDreamer Some properties are set and have data associated with them, some do not. You still need the ToString() call for the Website property, but unless data exists for a specific named property (EMail), you cannot call ToString() on it.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly `Membership.GetUser()` has returned null - is the client authenticated?

Maybe you need to put an `[Authorize]` attribute on your controller.

The debugger is your friend!